# Submenu not selecting

Tags: html, css

I can't select any submenu, when i move mouse on 1st menu it will show submenu when can't select submenu, it selects last menu's submenu only, what is wrong with my code?

here is my html code
HTML code

```
<div id="navbg">
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>

            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol">
            Section Name <br />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><br />
            <img src="images/ex.png" />

            </div>
            </div>
            </li>
        <li><a href="dedicated.html"><span>Dedicated Servers</span></a>
            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol">
            Section Name <br />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><br />
            <img src="images/ex.png" />

            </div>
            </div>
            </li>
        <li><a href="special-offers.html"><span>Special Offers</span></a>

            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol">
            Section Name <br />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><br />
            <img src="images/ex.png" />

            </div>
            </div>
            </li>
        <li><a href="datacenters.html"><span>Data Centers</span></a>


            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol">
            Section Name <br />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><br />
            <img src="images/ex.png" />

            </div>
            </div>

            </li>
        <li><a href="terms.html"><span>Terms</span></a>

            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol">
            Section Name <br />
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p><br />
            <img src="images/ex.png" />

            </div>
            </div></li>
        <li><a href="support.html"><span>Support</span></a>

            <div id="dedicated">
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>
            <div class="navcol"> 
            Section Name <br />
            <a href="#.html" class="ddlink" >Link goes here</a> <br /> 
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            <a href="#.html">Link goes here</a> <br />
            </div>

            </div></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code
CSS code

```
#navbg {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(195, 0, 42);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(195, 0, 42) 30%, rgb(166, 0, 28) 70%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(195, 0, 42) 30%, rgb(166, 0, 28) 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(195, 0, 42) 30%, rgb(166, 0, 28) 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(195, 0, 42) 30%, rgb(166, 0, 28) 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(195, 0, 42) 30%, rgb(166, 0, 28) 70%);
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a6001c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a6001c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(211, 65, 97, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(211, 65, 97, 1);
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(211, 65, 97, 1);
    }

#nav {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    }

#nav ul {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}   

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 13px 0px;
}

#nav li:hover {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #121212;
    padding: 13px 0px;
}


#nav span { padding: 0px 20px; }

#nav li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}


.ddlink {
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}   

#dedicated a:hover {
color: #c80c41; 
}
#dedicated p {
margin: 0; color: #fff;
line-height: 18px;
}

#dedicated {
width: 960px;
height: auto;
z-index: 999;
padding: 10px;
line-height: 26px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}   

#nav>ul>li:hover>div {
opacity: 1;
height: auto;
width: 960px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}   

#nav>ul>li>div {
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 181px;
background: #121212;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition: opacity .1s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity .1s linear;
-webkit-transition: opacity .1s linear;
-o-transition: opacity .1s linear;
z-index: 999;
border-bottom: 4px solid #aa0533;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
width: 960px;
}

.navcol { width: 200px; float: left; margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px; color: #c80c41;}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rpn2ex62/  when you have this much code, either simplify it or at least put it in a fiddle so people can see the issue

Comment: What is actual problem why to more brief about your problem instead of posting your entire code. Make a fiddle to tell whats wrong about

Comment: Try to select any submenu, it will shift to last menu's submenu
Ex. Home -> links goes here,  when you try to select it, it is selection Support -> link goes here

Comment: Couldn't hurt to throw a `position: relative;` on the `#nav` if you don't want the menu to shift over according to `position: relative;` on each respective parent `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you need to adjust is `top` of the following selector:

`#nav>ul>li:hover>div { top: 48px; }`

[see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpn2ex62/1/)

your code previously was using `#nav>ul>li>div { position: absolute; top: 187; ...}`

On :hover of the li, the child div was sitting 187px below the nav. I adjusted the `top` position of that div to be 48px.

Comment: put this `nav>ul>li:hover>div { top: 48px; }` in a code block rather than putting it bold

Comment: sorry but this is not i want, height is adjusted as per my whole page.

Comment: problem is if i select any submenu, selection shifting to last menu

Comment: puTTY@ can you explain little bit, what i was doing and how it works now

Comment: what if i want to move submenu to down, because as per my code top: 48px showing dropdown above menu bar

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. Can you send me a jsFiddle link? if you're referring to the position of the sub-menu, use your browsers inspector and adjust the `top` property position to your liking

Comment: your code has changed significantly. refer to the comments above, you should look into making the `nav` and `li` elements have relative positioning. The nav ought to work interdependently